# unable to sent email from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

my application is in online.

i have written the below code for sending email to the specified email address.

I am getting the flash message "email send successfully" but i am not able to receive the email . What could be the reason. Please help me!

controller.php:

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
      {   $this->load->library('email');
          $name=$this->input->post('fullname');
          $sendersemail=$this->input->post('email');
          $fromcountry=$this->input->post('countryname');
          $message=$this->input->post('contactdetails'); 
          $this->email->from($sendersemail, $name.'From'.$fromcountry);
          $this->email->to('a@gmail.com'); 
          $this->email->cc('b@yahoo.com'); 
          $this->email->bcc('c@gmail.com');  
          $this->email->subject('New Customer Contact from thmywebsite.com');
          $this->email->message($message);  
          $this->email->send(); 
          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Thankyou for contacting us .We will shortly  reply back on this ('.$this->input->post('email').') email ');
           redirect(current_url());
      }
```

**UPDATE:** after keeping debugger : i am getting output like this

```
    Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
    From: 
    Return-Path: 
    Cc: thbestbookfinder@yahoo.com
    Bcc: thebestbookfinder@gmail.com
    Reply-To: "lovesangprince@yahoo.com" 
    X-Sender: lovesangprince@yahoo.com
    X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
    X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
    Message-ID: <513e08c9def93@yahoo.com>
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_513e08c9defa1"


    =?utf-8?Q?New_Customer_Contact_from_thebestbookfinder.com?=
    This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
    Your email application may not support this format.

    --B_ALT_513e08c9defa1
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

    asd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf
    dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf
    dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf
    dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf
    dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsak


    --B_ALT_513e08c9defa1
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    asd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsak=
    asd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsak=
    asd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsak=
    asd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsak=
    asd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsakasd fsfsfs d hjfsdjf dsak

    --B_ALT_513e08c9defa1--
```

Comment: The `from` address should resolve to the server you're sending the message from. Use `reply-to` for the address that was entered

Comment: Next to this  $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Thankyou for contacting us .We will shortly  reply back on this ('.$this->input->post('email').') email '); put this and post the results echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: @Pekka웃  sorry i am not getting what you have explained. Please explain it litle.

Comment: The `from` address should be one from your server, not an arbitrary one entered by the user. Invalid `from` addresses are likely to be filtered out as spam. I would do `$this->email->from("myemail@mydomain.com");` and then `$this->email->replyTo($sendersemail, $name.'From'.$fromcountry);` (I'm assuming the class has a `replyTo()` method)

Comment: you have mention `$this->email->replyTo($sendersemail, $name.'From'.$fromcountry);`  That the replyTo method is already available in codeigniter library or i have to write it by my own?     It will be more helpful if you post it as answer by modify my above code.

Comment: @FabioAntunes As you said i kept `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` i am getting the message(please check my output in the above question)  . But still i not able to see my email in the inbox/spam folder  .Please help me

Comment: In your debbuger your from field is empty, are you sure $this->input->post('email') is passing an email?

Answer (score 0):

try put this code below $this->send->email

```
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

And check your spam if the email goes there